# Laravel 5 Apache Connections / Load average

Tags: apache, performance, laravel, laravel-5, load

I have a Laravel 5.0 application and some pure php applications running on Apache 2.2 server with Oracle 11g as database. After deployed the laravel app in to the server the load average went 0.2 to 0.4 which is ok at the moment. As this laravel app is a large number of visiting site I ran some load tests. When 10users /per second the server load average went 1.2. With 30users/per sec it went more than 15 and Apache make lots of oracle connections and cpu usage rise to 80%. We use persistant connection method so that load test finishes the connections will close slowly but load avarage keep more than 1.0. In the home page only 2 queries are executing and others are texts and images only.

I need to know how laravel performs with the apache when large request happens and methods to keep the request count low and load avarage below 1.0

Comment: To my knowledge Apache is a resource hog. I've done some load testing a while back using ab and when upping the concurrent requests after a certain limit Apache would eat up all CPU cycles, as well as spawning a considerable amount of processes and eating up quite a large amount of RAM. Did another load test using the same parameters but serving the app using nginx, the CPU barely went over 50% and memory usage was significantly lower.

Comment: My testing environment might not of had been the best in terms of configuration, but it does make sense that nginx is much more "reserved" when it comes to resources, considering that it was written to address the C10k problem. You might want to look into other HTTP servers performance, as there are a few alternatives to Apache.